# My .htaccess file seems to be blocking some data

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have just created a .htaccess file for a website and it appears to be blocking my database information from populating a dropdown menu. I am able to login fine with the password, but once I am there, the dropdown doesn't populate.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
AuthType Basic
AuthName "***Site Name***"
AuthUserFile /home/******/public_html/dev/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's far more likely that your code is faulty.  The .htaccess file knows nothing of your PHP code and cannot impact or impede it in this circumstance.  Turn on PHP error reporting to see what's going on in your code.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: (...unless you are making an HTTP request to access your database via some craziness in `file_get_contents('http://...')` or the like....)

Comment: It works perfectly if I remove the htaccess

Comment: Then you need to post your PHP code.  The addition of `AuthType Basic` alone cannot prevent your PHP from executing, except in a few very unusual cases

Comment: View your page source in the browser.  Do you see the PHP code rendered on screen? (if so, it is not executing at all, and the AddType is probably at fault)

Comment: Sorry, it appears that I have been given some bad information about how it works. There is no database involved so it is just pulling it from a .txt file.

Comment: Post your code then please. Sounds like there is a strange implementation here impeded by apache.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post back, I got caught up working on something else. The issue was that I was using a full path for getting data from a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446592/not-able-to-access-authorization-required-resource-with-jquerys-ajax